# Really need some help figuring out the logic of componentWillMount() prior to render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

this might be kind of long read, I've read and tried so many solutions without success! Essentially what I have is three MySQL tables, one with a list of users, and one with a list of file data. They are paired with a third table, which has a column for user id and a column for file id.

When a user logs into the app, it grabs their ID from Table 1, goes to Table 3, finds all the file IDs that are in the same row as their user ID, and then returns the file information from Table 2. Mostly straight forward, except it's not.

My current code:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.getClientFiles();
}
```

Which calls:

```
getClientFiles() {
        let id = this.props.currentUser.user_id;
        let file_refs = [];

        axios.get(`/users/get-client-files/${id}`)
          .then(res => {
            let response = res.data.response;

            for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                file_refs.push(response[i].file_id);
            }
            this.setState({
                file_refs
            });
            this.getFileData();
        });
    }
```

My understanding of this is that `this.getFileData();` should ONLY run once the axios GET request is successful (because of `.then`). The file refs are all returned, and the added to an array and put in state for the duration of the client's session.

Then this should run:

```
getFileData() {
    let fileRefs = this.state.file_refs;
    let fileData = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < fileRefs.length; i++) {
        axios
            .get("/files/get-file/" + fileRefs[i])
            .then(res => {
                fileData.push(res.data.response);
                this.setState({
                    client_files: fileData,
                    returned_data: true
                });
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data));
    }
}
```

Here, the function cycles through the fileRefs in state, makes a call for each reference ID, and returns that to fileData and saves it to state.

The problem.... on first page load after a login, the files do not render. If you hit cmd+R to refresh, boom there they are. I understand the chain of promises, and the async nature of JS functions, I understand that `componentWillMount()` should run prior to the mounting of the component, and that `setState` should trigger a re-render of a component.

Things I've tried:
1) Adding the following code in after `render()` prior to `return(` :

```
    if (this.state.returned_data === false) {
        this.getClientFiles();
    }
```

The result is a flickering of renders, 4-5 of them, as the functions run async before the state of returned_data is set to true.

2) Moving the `setState({ returned_data: true })` into the `getClientFiles()` function. This just ends the render early, resulting in no files until the page is refreshed.

3) Swapping out `componentWillMount()` for `componentDidMount()`.

Clearly, there is a fundamental aspect of the chain of functions and React's built in methods that I'm missing.

Can anybody help?

EDIT #1
The issue seems to be that on first render, `let id = this.props.currentUser.user_id;` is `undefined`, so the call in `getClientFiles` is actually going to `/users/get-client-files/undefined`

EDIT #2 - Requested by @devserkan
I hope this is what you wanted :)

First load
`get-client-files/${id}`: Returns an empty array
`/get-file/" + fileRefs[i]`: Doesn't run

Second load: 
`get-client-files/${id}`: Returns array with 5 items
`/get-file/" + fileRefs[i]`: Runs appropriately 5 times with the details of each file.

So clearly, the issue is with the fact that `get-client-files/${id}` isn't getting anything because it doesn't have the `${id}` to search from. The ID is passed down via props, but doesn't seem to be available immediately.

EDIT #3
Here is the function that gets the ID, and sets it to state.

```
getUser = () => {
    let localToken = localStorage.getItem("iod_tkn");

    axios({
        url: "/admins/current",
        method: "get",
        headers: {
            Authorization: localToken
        }
    })
        .then(result => {
            this.setState({
                isLoggedIn: true,
                user: result.data,
                user_id: result.data.user_id
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false });
            console.log(err);
        });
};
```

And App.js renders the following:

```
render() {
    const { loading } = this.state;

    if (loading) {
        return <Spinner />;
    }

    return (
            <AdminProvider>
                <FileProvider>
                    <Provider>
                        <Appbar isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn} logout={this.logout} />
                        <Main
                            getUser={this.getUser}
                            isLoggedIn={this.state.isLoggedIn}
                            currentUser={this.state.user}
                        />
                        <BottomNav />
                    </Provider>
                </FileProvider>
            </AdminProvider>

    );
}
```

So with passing `this.state.user` into Main.js, that component should re-render once the props have been received, right?

Comment: If you make this a CodeSandbox, I'll fix it for you.

Comment: I'll see what I can about getting it into a sandbox tomorrow, not sure how to go about that as it has so much tied into the code that I didn't post here (db etc.)

Ideally, I'm looking to understand WHY what I'm doing isn't working, though.

Comment: So, in the first place, if the `user_id` is undefined, you need to check other parts of your component.

Comment: Right but it returns the appropriate id after the page refreshes.. that's what I can't figure out.

Comment: Page refresh? Weird. How do you get this prop?

Comment: When the user logs in, the parent component (App.js) runs a function and pulls the user's id from the db, then passes it as a prop to ClientDashboard.js (the child component).

Comment: Ok, then you should do a conditional rendering. Before getting a response from DB, you are trying to render your component. Do something like that: `{  user_id && <ClientDashboard user_id={user_id} ... /> }`

Comment: omg it looks like that worked! if you stick your answer down below, i'll accept it.

Comment: Ok, I will provide an answer with some extra code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `user_id` is coming from an async job, you should do a conditional rendering. Like:

```
{ user_id && <ClientDashboard user_id={user_id} ... /> }
```

Also, you can clean up your code a little bit more maybe :) Here I am mimicking your app.

```js
const userFiles = [
  { file_id: 1, client_name: "foo" },
  { file_id: 2, client_name: "bar" },
  { file_id: 3, client_name: "baz" },
];

const files = [
  { file_id: 1, name: "fizz", size: 10 },
  { file_id: 2, name: "buzz", size: 20 },
  { file_id: 3, name: "fuzz", size: 30 },
];

const fakeRequest = () => new Promise( resolve =>
  setTimeout( () => resolve(userFiles), 1000)
);

const fakeRequest2 = id => new Promise(resolve => {
  const file = files.find( el => id === el.file_id );
  setTimeout(() => resolve(file), 1000)
}
);


class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    file_refs: [],
    client_files: [],
    returned_data: false,
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getClientFiles();
  }
  
  getClientFiles() {
    fakeRequest()
      .then(res => {
        const file_refs = res.map( el => el.file_id );
        
        this.setState({
          file_refs
        });

        this.getFileData();
      });
  }

  getFileData() {
    const {file_refs: fileRefs} = this.state;
    const promiseArray = fileRefs.map( id => fakeRequest2( id ) );

    Promise.all( promiseArray )
      .then( results => this.setState({
        client_files: results,
        returned_data: true,
      }))
  }
  
  render() {
    const { file_refs, client_files } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
      {!!file_refs.length && <p>File_refs: {JSON.stringify(file_refs)}</p>}
      {!!client_files.length && <p>Client files: {JSON.stringify(client_files)}</p>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

I don't like for loops :)

Comment: Solid. Thank you very much!

Comment: I take it back :( .... sometimes on login, it now just doesn't render (presumably because on first render there's no id.... but it isn't re-rendering automatically).

Comment: Ok then, where do you keep this `user_id`? React rerenders a component if its props or state change. So, you can keep it in the state, then after getting it set your state. When the parent's state changes it will be rerendered then `user_id` is no more undefined, the child gets `user_id`.

Comment: It's stored in state in App.js inside a user object. This object is passed down to Main.js as props, where the conditional routing occurs (i.e. if loggedin, and if user id exists, render route X).

Comment: Then I can't figure out where the problem is. If a prop changes the component itself must rerender no matter what. So, if `user_id` is coming from a parent, in the first render it will be `undefined`.This is what we expect. But after the async fetch, in the parent `user_id` will change via `setState` then it will rerender, so child's prop changes and it will rerender like the parent. Just follow the data where `user_id` is.

Comment: Yep, and that right there is exactly my own confusion! At any rate, I appreciate your help.... if I ever figure out what the issue is, I'll post :)

Comment: So, you pass the `user` not the `user_id` right? Then you should check the `user` not the `user_id` in the Child component.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's an issue with your code structuring. `setState` is an async function which takes a callback as a second parameter. You should take its advantage. You can execute a function after setState is finishing and utilize updated state using the second param callback (updater function) like:

```
this.setState({
    file_refs
}, () => {
    this.getFileData();
});
```

**EDITED** Second option you shouldn't setState `file_refs` unless you're using it in your render method.
Try this:

```
axios.get(`/users/get-client-files/${id}`)
      .then(res => {
        let response = res.data.response;

        for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            file_refs.push(response[i].file_id);
        }
        this.getFileData(file_refs);
    });

getFileData(file_refs) {
    let fileRefs = file_refs;
    let fileData = [];
    // rest of your code
}
```

Let me know if the issue still persists. Happy to help

Comment: See my edited answer. I hope this would help. Anyways if you can share codesandbox this would be helpful to fix the issue.

Comment: Sadly the Edit didn't work either :/ ... I'll see what I can about getting it into a sandbox tomorrow, not sure how to go about that as it has so much tied into the code that I didn't post here (db etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in `componentWillMount()` an async call might not retrieve the results on time before the render of the mount phase happens, so you will have unexpected side effects. Most probably the component will render with empty data.
The best place to render data from an async call is `componentDidMount()`.

As a side note, from 16.3 version on, `componentWillMount()` is considered an unsafe method of the lifecycle, and in future versions will be removed, so you better not use it anymore.

Comment: I am using componentDidMount() now due to the pending deprecation. However, this unfortunately doesn't solve the original issue of files not loading.