# Passing a function with React Context API to child component nested deep in the tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm using React Context API for the first time. I have a table that generates a list of clients. Originally, I stored the clients in an array in state, and in the same page I had a function that sorted the clients based on click.

I have moved the clients into context rather than in state of the actual page where the table is, but now of course my sort function no longer works. What I need to be able to do is use the same function, but organize the array that is in the context state instead.

Original function:

```
onSortClient = column => e => {
        const direction = this.state.sort.column
            ? this.state.sort.direction === "asc"
                ? "desc"
                : "asc"
            : "desc";
        const sortedData = this.state.clients.sort((a, b) => {
            if (column === "client_name") {
                const nameA = a.client_name.toUpperCase();
                const nameB = b.client_name.toUpperCase();
                if (nameA < nameB) {
                    return -1;
                }
                if (nameA > nameB) {
                    return 1;
                }

                return 0;
            }
            return 0;
        });

        if (direction === "desc") {
            sortedData.reverse();
        }

        this.setState({
            clients: sortedData,
            sort: {
                column,
                direction
            }
        });
    };
```

My context file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Context = React.createContext();

const Reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "DELETE_CLIENT":
            console.log(action.payload);
            return {
                ...state,
                clients: state.clients.filter(client => client.id !== action.payload)
            };
        case "ADD_CLIENT":
            return {
                ...state,
                clients: [action.payload, ...state.clients]
            };
        case "UPDATE_CLIENT":
            console.log(action.payload);
            return {
                ...state,
                clients: state.clients.map(
                    client =>
                        client.id === action.payload.id ? (client = action.payload) : client
                )
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export class Provider extends Component {
    state = {
        clients: [],
        loaded: false,
        dispatch: action => {
            this.setState(state => Reducer(state, action));
        }
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        let localToken = localStorage.getItem("iod_tkn");

        const res = await axios({
            url: "/users/get_clients",
            method: "get",
            headers: {
                Authorization: localToken
            }
        });

        this.setState({
            clients: res.data,
            loaded: true
        });
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <Context.Provider onSortClient={this.onSortClient} value={this.state}>
                {this.props.children}
            </Context.Provider>
        );
    }
}

export const Consumer = Context.Consumer;
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Future edit:**
As @ziggy pointed out in their comment, this causes a rerender for all consumers whenever this component is rendered, due to the object reference being recreated each time. Although there are some safeguards in place, given that the Context API is not a state manager, it's best to avoid using it in this manner and to explore other solutions instead.

---

Maybe something like that?

```
<Context.Provider
    value={{
        state: this.state,
        onSortClient: this.onSortClient,
    }}
>
    {this.props.children}
</Context.Provider>
```

So, `value.state` will be your state, `value.onSortClient` will be your function.

Comment: If you're pretty good at React, I have another question that nobody has been able to solve yet :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51994498/really-need-some-help-figuring-out-the-logic-of-componentwillmount-prior-to-re?noredirect=1#comment90940098_51994498

Comment: I feel it necessary to point out that if you use this code as is, every component that consumes this state will re-render every time this component re-renders. This is because you are creating a new object to pass to `value` every time this renders.

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats